# How can I move the position of a navbar logout button?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar with a welcome greeting for the user on the left, but I want to move my logout feature to the opposite side on the right. At the moment it sits beside the welcome. Any ideas on how to move it?
Here is my code that I have been using.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<!--navbar settings-->
           <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">


<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logout</a>-->

                <?php    //echo $_SESSION["staffname"];
            if(isset($_SESSION["staffId"]) && $_SESSION["staffId"] != NULL)
            {        ?> <a class="navbar-brand">
                     Welcome   <?php echo $_SESSION["staffname"];  ?></a>
               <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
             <?php
             }
             ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best way I would think of would be using div with class **.navbar-right** for logout link container:

```
<?php $isLoggedIn = (isset($_SESSION["staffId"]) && $_SESSION["staffId"] != NULL) ? true : false; ?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <!--navbar settings-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logout</a>-->

            <?php if($isLoggedIn): ?>
                <a class="navbar-brand">
                    Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["staffname"];  ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php if($isLoggedIn): ?>
            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: and where have you defined your `class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"`?

Comment: Do you mean where I defined css style itself? If yes, then nowhere, it's bootstrap classes

Answer (score 1):

Add the class pull-right to your a element :

```
 <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pull-right class

```
<a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
```

or give the anchor tag an id and style it by using `float: right;`

```
<style>
#lout
{float: right;}
</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
<!--navbar settings-->
           <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">


<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logout</a>-->

                <?php    //echo $_SESSION["staffname"];
            if(isset($_SESSION["staffId"]) && $_SESSION["staffId"] != NULL)
            {        ?> <a class="navbar-brand">
                     Welcome   <?php echo $_SESSION["staffname"];  ?></a>
               <a id = "lout" href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
             <?php
             }
             ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emkay992/L3cbm7bz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pull-right class on your anchor element:

```
<a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
```

Comment: <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand pull-right"><strong>Logout</strong></a>

Comment: @KeiranvanVuuren , dude update your answer with above comment. And don't put single line answer please.